# Adding corresponding elements of vectors C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have been doing a bit of brushing up on my Linear Algebra basics and figured a fun way to do so would be with code. I am trying to create a function that performs Vector addition given two vectors of different lengths. For example if we have two vectors v1 = 0, 7, 3 and v2 = 1, 2, 4 our sum would be 1, 9, 7. My end goal is to be able to create a function that accepts n number of vectors of any numeric type and perform traditional vector addition on them.

So far I am able to naively do so by just traversing the first vector and adding each element to the corresponding element of second vector.

```
int main() {
    // create vectors 
    std::vector<int> v1 = {0, 7, 3, 4}; 
    std::vector<int> v2 = {1, 2, 4, 1, 6}; 
    
    int i = 0;
    // iterate over v1 adding to the corresponding element in v2
    for (i; i < v1.size(); i++) {
        int sum = v1[i] + v2[i];
        printf("sum - %d\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What would the logic look like to add the elements of two vectors of different sizes?

Comment: *'What would the logic look like to add the elements of two vectors of different sizes?'* -- If you are still thinking of linear algebra, then it doesn't make any sense to add two vectors of different sizes.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep very very good point thank you very much. had been so focused on the implementation I skipped over this essential rule :/

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<int> sum;
for (int i=0; i < std::min(v1.size(),v2.size()); i++) {
    sum.push_back(v1[i] + v2[i]);
}
```

or

```
vector<int> sum;
for (int i=0; i < std::max(v1.size(),v2.size()); i++) {
    int a=0;
    if(i<v1.size()) a += v1[i];
    if(i<v2.size()) a += v2[i];
    sum.push_back(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The requirements of your question are summarized as

1. an function that accepts different types to sum up on vectors;
2. the sum function may encounter different lengths of vectors;

### 1. Use template to define generic functions

Suppose you take the first arg `lhs` to store the result.

```
template<typename LHS, typename RHS>
void vsum(LHS& lhs, RHS const& rhs) {
    assert(lhs.size() == rhs.size());
    auto lhs_iter = lhs.begin();
    auto rhs_iter = rhs.cbegin();
    while(lhs_iter != lhs.end() && rhs_iter != rhs.cend()) {
        *lhs_iter += *rhs_iter;
        ++lhs_iter; 
        ++rhs_iter;
    }
}

std::vector<double> lhs{1.2, 3.4, 5.6};
std::vector<int>    rhs{7, 8, 9};

vsum(lhs, rhs);
```

Then variable `lhs` now hold the sum vector result.

Note that I use `assert` here to check length in debug phase, which mean the inputs are **guaranteed to be valid length** in `vsum` function. Comment this assert sentence, you will get a minimum length version.

### 2. Careful check and prepare inputs

To Answer 2, it is alway not the result as you expected when accepting the default minimum length of your input vectors. It is a good practice to [throw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw), or at least print a warning message in logger or to `std::cerr` when inputs does not met your constrain that "vectors on different dimension cannot be added" in linear algebra.

To keep input clean and tidy, provide a project function to map vector of higher dim to given dim. It is simple and straightforward.

```cpp
template<std::size_t DIM, typename T>
void project(std::vector<T>& vec) {
    vec.resize(DIM, T(0));
}

constexpr int k_physical_dim = 3;
std::vector<double> data_vec{3.4, 5.6};
project<k_physical_dim>(data_vec);
```

By this, you trim `data_vec` to specific dimension you are working on.

### 3. Get familiar with <algorithm.h> header

When get familiar with template and C++ type operations, it is strongly advised to use algorithm lib instead. You can read reference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Hope this may help you.

Comment: this solution led me onto a tangent regarding the auto keyword as well as generics, but how would I go about printing the result from vsum()? I was thinking something like auto sum = vsum(lhs, rhs); and doing cout << sum << << endl; but of course that is not how it works

Comment: @aaries sorry about the “auto” as return type. The first version of this answer returns a type a derived container of decltype<element_t<lhs>+element_t<rhs>> . But it is too complicated  and degreed for the origin question. It is then simplified as current version but return type is left unintended.

Comment: no worries at all! I found your first part was of great use to what I am trying to implement. The idea is to declare and initialize our vectors of any type (int, float, etc) in main() and calling a sum() function passing in the initialized vectors and being able to print out the result. I am confused on how to accomplish this with auto